# Combining rows dynamically in sql

Tags: c#, sql, group-by, pivot, window-functions

I know there are similarly worded questions but I can't seem to find one that fits my specific case. I have something that more or less looks like this:

```
GUID  | FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME | LOAN_NUMBER | LOAN_AMOUNT
---------------------------------------------------------
0001  | FIRST      | LAST      | 01          | 1000
0001  | FIRST      | LAST      | 02          | 1500
0002  | SECOND     | PERSON    | 03          | 1250
0002  | SECOND     | PERSON    | 04          | 2000
0002  | SECOND     | PERSON    | 05          | 1250
```

etc (any person can have any number of different loans for different amounts)...

and I need it to look like this:

```
GUID | FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME | LOAN_AMOUNT1 | LOAN_AMOUNT2 | LOAN_AMOUNT3
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
0001 | FIRST      | LAST      | 1000         | 1500         |
0002 | SECOND     | PERSON    | 1250         | 2000         | 1250
```

this sql result is going to end up getting passed into a C# application in any case, so if this is more easily done in c# then I may go that route instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` to rank each person's loans, and then pivot with conditional aggregation:

```
select
    guid,
    first_name,
    last_name,
    max(case when rn = 1 then loan_amount end) loan_amount1,
    max(case when rn = 2 then loan_amount end) loan_amount2,
    max(case when rn = 3 then loan_amount end) loan_amount3
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        row_number() over(partition by guid order by loan_number) rn
    from mytable t
) t
group by guid, first_name, last_name
```

If you need to handle more than 3 loans per person, you can extend the `select` clause with more conditional expressions.

Comment: Ah, it worked perfectly! I'm still relatively inexperienced in SQL and hadn't even seen the row_number stuff before, thanks a ton!